# Pandas dataframe merge not working as expected with multiple column equality checks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge based on two columns being equal to each other for two Dataframes.

Here is the code:

```
>>> df.merge(df1, how='left', left_on=['Name', 'Age'], right_on=['Name', 'Age'], suffixes=('', '_@'))
   Name  Age
0     1    2
1     3    4
2     4    5
>>> df
   Name  Age
0     1    2
1     3    4
0     4    5
>>> df1
   Name  Age
0     5    6
1     3    4
0     4    7
```

What I actually expected from the merge was

```
   Name  Age  Age_@
0     1    2    NaN
1     3    4    4.0
2     4    5    7.0
```

Why does pandas think that there all three matching rows for this merge?

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.merge` returns a **dataframe** object. It's basically just a wrapper for `pandas.merge` that uses the current dataframe as input for the keyword argument `left` (if my understanding of backend pandas is correct).

Can you try saving the output of `df.merge(...` into df like so `df = df.merge(...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mean `merge` on `Name` right ?

```
df.merge(df1, how='left', on='Name', suffixes=('', '_@'))
Out[120]: 
   Name  Age  Age_@
0     1    2    NaN
1     3    4    4.0
2     4    5    7.0
```

Using `indicator` to see what is your output

```
df.merge(df1, how='left', left_on=['Name', 'Age'], right_on=['Name', 'Age'], suffixes=('', '_@'),indicator=True)
Out[121]: 
   Name  Age     _merge
0     1    2  left_only
1     3    4       both
2     4    5  left_only
```

Since you `df` and `df1` have the same `columns` and all of the `columns` had been used as `merge` key , so there is not other `columns` indicate whether they share the same items in df or not (since you using the `left` , so that the default is show all left items in the result ).

Comment: No actually, I would like to merge on Name and Age

Comment: Actually, the copy paste I showed you for what I wanted was from running the same exact code you ran. I just expected that a merge on both Name and Age would give the same results, but confused to as why it's not